# C# .NET DirectoryInfo : FileSystemInfo Class members

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.file

I'm confused with how `DirectoryInfo` class methods work. For example: `public void Create();`
This method *does not have* curly braces and I'm just confused how does it actually create a directory? What am I missing?

Comment: "_This method does not have curly braces_" Where are you seeing it defined like that?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directoryinfo.cs,368db83772a7dab0

Comment: Are you looking [at the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.create?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_Create)? That's just the docs' way of showing the method signature -- it doesn't mean that the method has no body.

Comment: I assume you are using Visual Studio to navigate to the methods, that will not show you the method content, only the class and method signatures. If you want to see what is inside, view the source code on Github or use a tool to decompile the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

> ## DirectoryInfo :
>
> Exposes instance methods for creating, moving, and enumerating through
>    directories and subdirectories. This class cannot be inherited
>
> ## DirectoryInfo.Create :
>
> It's used to Creates a directory.

***Exemple :***

```
    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo("you path directory");

    try 
    {
        // check if you directory exists.
        if (directory.Exists) 
        {
            // if you directory exists.
            return;
        }

        //otherwise you create you directory.
        directory.Create();

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
    }
```

***source:*** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

You see only its' methods names because that is just a way to show you public methods via C#, you can't see the code of a library if you don't own its' source code!